# How to get the source code of the built-in function of Clang compiler?

Tags: clang, clang++, built-in

here are some built-in functions about atomic operations [in the documentation](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/a3e6e624c71d60509c84e13ea3ee96c0acde65c3/clang/docs/LanguageExtensions.rst):

- `__c11_atomic_init`
- `__c11_atomic_thread_fence`
- `__c11_atomic_store`
- `__c11_atomic_load`
- `__c11_atomic_exchange`
- `__c11_atomic_compare_exchange_strong`
- `__c11_atomic_compare_exchange_weak`
- `__c11_atomic_fetch_add`

...

I want to look at the source code implemented by Clang? Their implementation may be in a source file, but I did not find it.

Comment: These are intrinsics, not library functions, so there is no source code in the library sense. The compiler understands them natively, the same way it understands "int" or "if" or "+". [They turn directly into abstract instructions](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/f22fbe3a152ed1e7712c6580405cb28db00187a5/clang/lib/CodeGen/CGAtomic.cpp#L523).

Comment: @RaymondChen Post it as an answer ;)